# Why isn't my font-size working in my h1, h2, p

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am writing code for an About Me page. I used classes for columns for the layout. I am not sure why I can't adjust the sizing of the font-size but can adjust everything else in the code.

I have tried:

```
h1 { 
    font-size: 13 px; ( also %, ems)
}
```

but the font size stays the same.

Here's my css file:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

I was told it could have something to do with this (but i don't know what):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ABOUT ME: Kim Stahlbaum</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Add all changes to the custom.css file only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom2.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
</html>
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="column2of2">
      <h1>Who Am I?</h1>
        <p>Hi, my name is Kim, and I am a graphic designer with 10 years experience, emerging into the web design world. <br /> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to tell your html to use the css for styling

Comment: Have you checked whether your h1 style is being overwritten by another CSS rule?

Comment: Typo: Do not put a space between the number of the uni for a length.

Comment: Please put this in your head file
<link rel='stylesheet' id='custom'  href='css/custom2.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
Or check in inspect your style is apply or not.

Comment: First step: fix the typo as pointed out in another comment. Second step: use the Inspector (try `F12`) to figure out if your stylesheet file is even being loaded and whether or not your rule is being applied to the `h1` element.